# Focusin and Focus out in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a input type i want to add focus in and focus out functionality on the focusin i want to set blank value of the input type on focus out i want to do a patter match that the input value will be like this 
any character or character plus ,.This will be the format but the focus and focusout is not working for me

e.g **c** or **c,d**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" name="nameClass" id="nameClass">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#nameClass').live('focus', function() {
    //set the value to blank
});
$('#nameClass').live('blur', function() {
    //check the pattern 
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is removed in curent jQuery version.  SO use `.on()` event handler attachment.

Comment: use `.on` instead of `.live`

Comment: [Here's a JSFiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/yWZeY/) - doesn't seem to have a problem as to what I can see. I might just be misunderstanding the question though.

Comment: "patter match that the input value will be like this any character or character plus" - what does this mean?

Comment: @webeno it can be either a character or comma seperated character

Comment: so you meant "patter **N** match", right?

Comment: What have you tried with the pattern matching so far? We can't do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the functionality you're looking for -

```
$('selector').blur(function(){

})

$('selector').focus(function(){

})
```